# I have a progress bar clipping issue in layer list

Tags: android, android-layout

Im creating a horizontal progress bar with circles at relevant points =

[image]

the problem is that when i add progress it fill the whole container of the progress bar =

[image]

So obviously i just want to fill to progress bar itself.
i cant quite work out what Im doing wrong.

Heres my xml =

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/progressHolder"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#C7C7C7"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <size android:width="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:gravity="top|center">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="#C7C7C7"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="#C7C7C7"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="#C7C7C7"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        >
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="#C7C7C7"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/progress">
        <clip
            android:clipOrientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="bottom">
            <shape>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/info_blue"/>
                <corners
                    android:radius="10dp"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

So i thought clipping the blue progress, would clip the blue edges around my grey progress bar, But this doesnt seem to be the case.

Any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The progress bar is simply a drawable that is positioned on top of another drawable. The top drawable is clipped to cover/expose the bottom drawable. You are laying a rectangle on top of your background so, as the progress increases, more and more of the background is covered by the rectangle. (In short, `ProgressBar` is not smart in the way that it will fill in the color of the background.)

So, you will need two drawables: The background drawable which is the gray color and the top which is the blue. Something like this will work:

**progress_unfilled.xml**

```
<layer-list>

    <item android:id="@+id/progressHolder"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#C7C7C7"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <size android:width="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:gravity="top|center">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="#C7C7C7"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="#C7C7C7"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="#C7C7C7"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        >
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="#C7C7C7"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**progress_filled.xml** is the same but with the color `@color/info_blue`.

Now, we will place these into `progress_drawable.xml`:

**progress_drawable.xml**

```
<layer-list>

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_unfilled"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip
            android:clipOrientation="vertical"
            android:drawable="@drawable/progress_filled"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and the XML layout file:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:progress="75"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what displays:

[image]

For API 21+, if you use `progressBackgroundTint` then only one drawable is needed for the progress bars.